# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" while using mongoose ODM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, push, mongoose-schema

Below is the snippet of my code where I am getting the above mentioned error. Basically I want to find topic in my collection using the id and then pushing the comment onto it (array). I have used mongoose model in my project.

```
Topic.findById(id)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    topic = result,
    topic.comments.push(comm);
    topic.save()
    .then((result) => {
        res.redirect("/topics/:id");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  })
```

I have also tried other options which is I think is more incorrect. I will be writing them in comments if it helps. :)

Comment: Topic.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $push: { comments: comm  } },
    function (error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(success);
      }
    }
  );

Comment: mongoose.connection.db.collection("topics").updateOne(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $push: { comments: comm  } },
    function (error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(success);
        res.redirect("/topics/:id");
      }
    }
  );

Comment: It seems to me that your `comments` property is not initialized. For the returned `topic` property `comments` is not set, or initialized as an array object.  Check if `comments` is undefined and then before push initialize it with [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the my TopicSchema, I just initiated the comments array like below and it worked!

```
comments: {
    type: Array,
    required: false
}
```